# I'm having trouble running the program (run model.fit)

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_21 to have shape (10,) but got array with shape (1,)

Comment: Without more detail, your question is unlikely to see a useful answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips.

Comment: Please can you share sample code or trace block to make it clear about your error message.